# How to interpret TensorFlow's convolution filter and striding parameters?

Tags: python, filter, convolution, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand TensorFlow's [convolution](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn.md#convolution), in particular the formula

```
shape(output) = [batch,
             (in_height - filter_height + 1) / strides[1],
             (in_width - filter_width + 1) / strides[2],
             ...]
```

I would have expected the formula to be

```
shape(output) = [batch,
             (in_height - filter_height) / strides[1] + 1,
             (in_width - filter_width) / strides[2] + 1,
             ...]
```

instead. Starting from a 32x32 image, and applying a 5x5 filter with strides [1,3,3,1], then in my understanding this should yield a 10x10 output, whose values are the convolutions of the areas

```
 (0:4,0:4) ,  (0:4,3:7) ,  (0:4,6:10) , ...,  (0:4,27:31), 
 (3:7,0:4) ,  (3:7,3:7) ,  (3:7,6:10) , ...,  (3:7,27:31),
...
(27:31,0:4), (27:31,3:7), (27:31,6:10), ..., (27:31,27:31)
```

so both dimensions should be floor((32-5)/3)+1=10 and not floor((32-5+1)/3)=9. What am I missing here? Have I misunderstood the way convolution is done here and/or what the parameters mean? If so, what parameters should I use in order to obtain the above selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [issue #196](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/196), this part of the documentation is apparently wrong; and I think there is still problem in dga's answer.

It should be:

floor((in_height+y_padding-filter_height)/y_stride) + 1,

- When padding=VALID, y_padding=0.
- When padding=SAME, in general y_padding should be adjusted to make (in_height+y_padding-filter_height)/y_stride an integer so that 'floor' becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct - it should be:

ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))

For 32, 5, stride=3, this becomes:  ceil(9.33) = 10.

Fixed and will be pushed into github soon.  Thanks for catching this!  For more info, see the [github bug discussion, issue #196](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/196)