# tensorflow: filters vs kernels and strides

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

Python 3.5 / Windows 10 / tensorflow-gpu 1.12 (GTX 1070)

Goal: Build a convolution autoencoder for 3 channel images

Tutorial Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/autoencoders-introduction-and-implementation-3f40483b0a85

This tutorial uses the MNIST data set, my images are larger and in 3 color channels, but I am trying to adapt accordingly.

A point of confusion for me is here:

```
inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 28, 28, 1), name='inputs')

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=inputs_, filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Now 28x28x32
```

[28,28,1] is the w/h & gray-scale of the the mnist image

I understand the kernel_size to be equivalent to the filter size -- **is this correct?** (https://blog.xrds.acm.org/2016/06/convolutional-neural-networks-cnns-illustrated-explanation/)

Using the same Kernel/Filter & Stride understanding shown here:
[image: kernel/stride]

My understanding of deriving a feature map:

I wouldn't have padded the above image, and would have arrived at the following:

```
filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a = calc_num_filters(shapeXY=[5,5,1], filterXY=[3,3], strideXY=[1,1])
print("# Filters: {}\nNew Shape: {}\n Padding : {}".format(filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a))
# Filters: 9
New Shape: [3, 3, 1]
 Padding : [0, 0]
```

given that it is padded:

```
filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a = calc_num_filters(shapeXY=[5,5,1], filterXY=[3,3], strideXY=[1,1], paddingXY=[1,1])
print("# Filters: {}\nNew Shape: {}\n Padding : {}".format(filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a))

5.0
# Filters: 25
New Shape: [5, 5, 1]
 Padding : [1, 1]
```

---

I interpret the number of filters to be a function of the image size, padding, stride, and kernel size. (**Is this correct?**) ([How to interpret TensorFlow's convolution filter and striding parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738440/how-to-interpret-tensorflows-convolution-filter-and-striding-parameters))

My dummy calculation of this relationship is as follows:

```
def calc_num_filters(shapeXY, filterXY, strideXY=[1,1], paddingXY = [0,0]):
    paddingX = paddingXY[0]
    while True:
        filtersX = 1 + ((shapeXY[0]+2*paddingX-filterXY[0])/strideXY[0])
        if filtersX == int(filtersX):# and filtersX%2 == 0:
            break
        paddingX += 1
        if paddingX >= shapeXY[0]:
            raise "incompatable filter shape X"

    paddingY = paddingXY[1]
    while True:
        filtersY = 1 + ((shapeXY[1]+2*paddingY-filterXY[1])/strideXY[1])
        if filtersY == int(filtersY):# and filtersY%2 == 0:
            break
        paddingY += 1
        if paddingY >= shapeXY[1]:
            raise "incompatable filter shape Y"

    return (int(filtersX*filtersY),[int(filtersX), int(filtersY), shapeXY[2]],  [paddingX, paddingY])
```

In the tutorial example, conv1 changes the tensor size from [28, 28, 1] to [28, 28,32]. I've noticed that `tf.layers.conv2d` seems to make the channel (or z-dim) match the `filters` value passed in all cases.

**I can't figure out how these values are compatible: a `28x28 image`, with a `kernel_size=(3,3)` resulting in `32 filters`?**

Assuming stride = [1,1]

```
filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a = calc_num_filters(shapeXY=[28,28,1], filterXY=[3,3], strideXY=[1,1])
print("# Filters: {}\nNew Shape: {}\n Padding : {}".format(filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a))

# Filters: 676
New Shape: [26, 26, 1]
 Padding : [0, 0]
```

Using a `strideXY=[3,3]`:

```
filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a = calc_num_filters(shapeXY=[28,28,1], filterXY=[3,3], strideXY=[3,3])
print("# Filters: {}\nNew Shape: {}\n Padding : {}".format(filter_ct_a, out_shape_a, padding_a))
# Filters: 100
New Shape: [10, 10, 1]
 Padding : [1, 1]
```

**If filter (count), kernel size, stride, and image size are related in the way that I understand them to be -- why does tensorflow ask for the filter count when it could be derived?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of filters is **NOT** at all related to either of kernel size, stride or image size. Rather, it is specified by you using the `filters` argument. For example when you set `filters=32` it means this layer would have 32 **independent** convolution filters in that sense each one will be applied on the given image, which has a shape of `(28, 28, 1)` in your example, and will return a feature map (i.e. activation map) of shape `(28, 28)` (assuming `padding='same'`). Therefore, all the filters combined, the output of convolution layer would have a shape of `(28, 28, 32)`. If you had set `filter=53` the output of convolution layer would be of shape `(28, 28, 53)`, i.e. again one feature map per convolution filter.

Comment: tracking -- so this is where we add domain knowledge to indicate the number of features? Or throw the farm (Ram/GPU max) to brute-force domain insight? Is that a better interpretation of the filter selection?

Comment: @Schalton Setting hyperparameters such as the number of units or filters is mostly based on experience and there is no concrete formula for that. Further, it depends on the problem you are working on and data you have. For example, in CNN model usually (but not always) the number of filters increase as we go deeper in the model and they are usually a power of two (i.e. 16, 32, 64, ...).

Comment: in retrospect it looks like I was co-mingling the idea of pooling/pool_size with filters/filter size -- given that, is my understanding of pool_size accurate?

Comment: @Schalton Well, the pooling is usually done to downsample the output of a Conv layer. For example, a pooling layer with a pool size of 2 would produce an output of shape `(w/2, h/2, c)` given an input of shape `(w, h, c)` (i.e. it is only applied on spatial dimension). And like kernel size, it is a hyperparameter that is specified by you (i.e. designer of the model) and it is not determined by other values (like image size, etc.).

Comment: Perfect -- that was my confusion, the stride and pool dims dictate the number of pooled matrices (not filters).

I'm playing with building an autoencoder for full HD images. Pooling to downsample the image (to stay within RAM/GPU constraints) and filtering to provide dimensionality to maintain 'detail' -- so my encoder will invert the 'normal' filter schema. Trading filter depth for pixel detail. Then I'll use the encoded images as my training set for another network.

So I need to add filters before pooling to preserve detail.

Thanks! This helped my understanding tremendously!